# Kusto Query to get Http5xx by Instance level

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks

I have Azure Function Apps running in App Service, and I am able to get the number of Http Server Errors by instance level in the Metrics (Pls see image). I would like to get the same level of metics via Kusto query and tried all the Log tables I can't find it. Is it possible to get those metrics by instance using Kusto?

I checked in AzureMetrics there is no instance level data stored: Here is the query I am using to get all Http Server Errors overall.

[image]

```
AzureMetrics  
| where ResourceGroup == "RG"
| where TimeGenerated {TimeRange}
| where ResourceId in ("ResourceId")
| where MetricName == "Http5xx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking at Azure Metrics in metrics explorer, those generally are *NOT* coming from a kql backed data source (not all standard azure metrics are in any workspaces/etc for cost/compat reasons)

in workbooks, instead of using a `Query` step, you'd use a `Metrics` step to get this data instead.  you'd pick that time range parameter in the time range dropdown, likewise you'd select the appropriate resource type and that resources or resource parameter in the resource picker of the metrics item, and you'd add that metric.  (there's a preview feature coming to help with this, add `?feature.sendtoworkbooks=true` to your azure portal url, like https://portal.azure.com/?feature.sendtoworkbooks=true) and the Metrics Explorer view will have additional "Send to workbooks" options in the share and pin menus that will convert the metrics view to a workbook)

If Application Insights is configured on this function app, you could possibly query the appinsights `customMetrics` table to get *custom* metrics in the function app, but probably not the *standard* metrics as KQL)

Comment: Thanks for the details, Yes I was using metrics in Workbooks the thing was I can't use more than one function apps (Via Parameters), if I select more than one function apps in parameter then I don't see the split(by instance options) in the workbooks/metrics  thats why I was looking for a way to query.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly your question, in workbooks, if you pick multiple resources the chart is *implicitly* split by the resource.  if you switch to grid mode you can do additional/other grouping as well.